# Can we use the alternating series test on $\sin(x)$ alone?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Say we have some series

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sin\frac{1}{n^2}
$$

Can I use the alternating series test to show that it is convergent? It doesn't have a $(-1)^n$ term but it oscillates between -1 and 1 anyways. Where $a_n = \sin\frac{1}{n^2}$, it clearly decreases for all n > 1 and $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin\frac{1}{n^2} = 0$$ which, if the alternating series test were applicable, would imply that this series is convergent, which it is. Intuitively, it does not seem applicable since having a $(-1)^n$ term seems different than having a function like sin but I'm not sure why.

It's not immediately obvious to me that $\sin\frac{1}{n^2} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$ which that seems like the easier route to show that the series absolutely converges. Is there an easy way to see the comparison right off the bat?

Comment: $\sin (\frac 1 {n^{2}})>0$ for all $n$.  $\sin x \leq x$ for al $x \geq 0$.

Comment: Consider the function $f(x)=x-\sin(x)$ which has derivate $f'(x)=1-\cos(x)$ which is everywhere non-negative and $0$ in isolated points. Therefore, $f(x)$ is strictly increasing and can have at most one root , which can easily be guessed : $x=0$. Because of $f(\pi)=\pi>0$ , we have $x>\sin(x)$ for every positive $x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(\frac{1}{n})$ does NOT converge (by the comparison test with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n}$) . You need both positive and negative terms to use the alternating series test.